# What punctuation mark should I use here? A comma or semi-colon?

Tags: punctuation

I have the sentence:

> The stock market is both influential; and influenced by these areas.

What punctuation should I use between the words "influential" and "and"?

Comment: None. Don't separate two parts of a compound complement.

Comment: If this question isn't merely a request for proofreading help (a category of questions off topic at this site), you need to explain why the issue you intend to raise here is relevant to something more than this particular set of words.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You should not put any punctuation mark there,because the word 'and' is being used only once in the sentence

Comment: I'm afraid this is wrong. Style guides will advise no punctuation because the words after *and* form a compound complement and not an independent clause. They would advise a comma in *The stock market is influential, and it is influenced by those areas* and there's still only one *and*.

Comment: @deadrat is right, I dunno why this answer was selected. Probably cause it's the only one that was posted.